# Python subprocess pipes

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I would just like to have more understanding with `subprocess.popen` and `pipes`.  Main questions are

1. Where does it save the contents of the pipe (memory or file system)?
2. Does it act like an iterator, where when I read/iterate through it, those content are deleted?
3. If I use bufsize in Popen, how does it work?  Does it pause/block the subprocess until some of the content from the pipe is read?

For example, lets say I have `main.py` below:

```
import subprocess
import time


class SubprocessReader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', "mysubprocess.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            line = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                raise StopIteration
            return line


a = SubprocessReader()
for word in a:
    print(word)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

And `mysubprocess.py` contains:

```
for x in range(1000000000):
    print("writing {}".format(x))
```

So with this example, the subprocess writes much faster to the pipe, since the parent is reading it and sleep for half a second.  I would think this will use a lot of memory/space after a while.  I dont see any additional memory use with htop though.  So the question arises, where does the stdout/print out from subprocess being saved to?  And if I remove the sleep from main.py, would it technically not use any additional memory/space?  Since as soon as the subprocess writes into the pipe, the main process reads it and remove it from memory? Is that how it works?

And if I do this in main.py instead of looping

```
a = SubprocessReader()
a.proc.wait()
```

I still dont see any increase in memory or anything with htop. So I am really confused where the data is being saved.

Finally, if I use `bufsize`, would it block the subprocess when it reach that size, and continue when some of the content is read?

Comment: The pipes are in RAM, and have a fixed maximum size.  Once they're full, the writing process is blocked until room is made available (due to the reading process consuming some of the data).